# How to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH (and maybe DYLD_ as well) for google protobuf on mac?

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, caffe

`protobuf` 2.5 has been installed (via `brew`) and is in the path:

```
$which protoc
/usr/local/opt/protobuf@2.5/bin/protoc
```

When compiling (`caffe`) it is not being found: presumably due to library path settings.

```
ld: library not found for -lprotobuf
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

Which env vars need to be updated? I am unclear among which combination of

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
LIBRARY_PATH
```

were required

Also: is the following path `/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf@2.5/2.5.0/lib` correct to use?

```
$ll /usr/local/Cellar/protobuf@2.5/2.5.0/lib
total 12392
-r--r--r--   1 boescst  admin  1120832 Feb 26  2013 libprotoc.a
-r--r--r--   1 boescst  admin  1536576 Feb 26  2013 libprotobuf.a
-r--r--r--   1 boescst  admin   215672 Feb 26  2013 libprotobuf-lite.a
drwxr-xr-x  12 boescst  admin      408 Feb 26  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 boescst  admin      136 Mar 12 11:46 pkgconfig
-r--r--r--   1 boescst  admin   659108 Mar 12 11:46 libprotoc.dylib
-r--r--r--   1 boescst  admin   659108 Mar 12 11:46 libprotoc.8.dylib
-r--r--r--   1 boescst  admin   930424 Mar 12 11:46 libprotobuf.dylib
-r--r--r--   1 boescst  admin   930424 Mar 12 11:46 libprotobuf.8.dylib
-r--r--r--   1 boescst  admin   138008 Mar 12 11:46 libprotobuf-lite.dylib
-r--r--r--   1 boescst  admin   138008 Mar 12 11:46 libprotobuf-lite.8.dylib
drwxr-xr-x  11 boescst  admin      374 Mar 12 11:46 ..
```

Finally:  do I need to make any symbolic links inside that directory - to make the calling program (`caffe` in my case ) be able to find the libs?

The libraries included are shown in the `Makefile` as so:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS += $(BLAS_INCLUDE)
LIBRARY_DIRS += $(BLAS_LIB)
LIBRARY_DIRS += /usr/local/Cellar/protobuf@2.5/2.5.0/lib


LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir)) $(PKG_CONFIG) 
        $(foreach library,$(LIBRARIES),-l$(library))
```

So is there a way to print out these libraries - without resorting to `make -d` that generates *265K* lines?

Comment: This looks like a compiler linker error, not a missing run path; you might want to include the compile command in your question. Normally you would do something similar to `-L/path/to/lib -lprotobuf`...

Comment: @l'L'l  Thanks!  I'll add that

Comment: @l'L'l  Updated the OP: It is not clear how to show the libraries included from the `Makefile` directive

Comment: Maybe try adding `LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf@2.5/2.5.0/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH` to your `Makefile` below `INCLUDE_DIRS`. This is how a path is set generally at compile time. If it's a run path issue then you would use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`...

Comment: @l'L'l  Thx. Added it - see updated OP. No change in behavior/errors.

Comment: Use `LIBRARY_PATH` instead, this might confirm that it is indeed a linker issue. If that doesn't work then you should look at the library `.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3` to see where it's trying to find `libprotobuf`. Also, be sure to `make clean` before you run `make` again...

Comment: @l'L'l  Ah!  I was looking at wrong `Makefile`;  adding the `LIBRARY_PATH` did work. Please add as an answer.

Comment: @l'L'l  Specifically the change required is to add to `LIBRARY_DIRS` : i will update the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the compiler returns the error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This indicates that a particular library attempting to be linked is unable to be located. In most cases it's usually a matter of informing the compiler where the library in question actually is. There are several ways to do this, and it depends on the way something is being built. Since you are using a `Makefile` adding the following environment variable should resolve the issue:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf@2.5/2.5.0/lib:$LIBRA‌​RY_PATH
```

This adds the libraries location temporarily in the environment so the compiler is able to locate it.

**NOTE**: In the case `LIBRARY_PATH` isn't recognized, `LIBRARY_DIRS` is the correct variable to use.

Comment: thx a lot.  I have follow-on question:  The `-lprotobuf` error was fixed.  Now I get `-lboost_python` .   I am wondering if it were going to be necessary to *manually* add each and every library to the path..  Is there some more general way to fix this?  `ld: library not found for -lboost_python`

Comment: I think the main issue is that the compiler is expecting the libraries to be in a standard location. I don't use Homebrew, although I would think there should be a way update the paths it's using in such cases. Where is the `libboost_python` located? You can always set the paths in your `~/.bash_profile` perhaps and then it would be globally set.

Comment: agreed about standard libraries location.  Actually turns out `boost_python` were simply not installed yet - so my bad.  It did pick it up now